# Unzoomable element

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scale

I want to make `div` with size equal to 1 screen pixel regardless current browser zoom.

It's important for me that this element will be as small as possible, but will cause line break if the next element tries to get same size as container or larger.

I used `1px` but when page zoom is less then 100% it gets unstable - sometimes it works, but sometimes Chrome shrinks element to 0 and does not wrap the next element. So I hoped to enlarge element on other zooms, but I don't know how to detect it.

Seems like on my computer next snippet works fine, but in the real code similar thing works unstable if browser zoom is less than 100%. **In this example I want red div to take 1px of the screen width regardless current zoom.** Is that possible?

```js
~function () {
  var s = "When silver div gets too wide it should jump down..."
  var i = s.length
  var div = document.querySelector(".content");

  setInterval(function () {
    div.textContent = s.slice(0, i = ++i % (s.length + 1))
  }, 100)
}()
```

```css
section {
  width: 15em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.narrow {
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.content {
  background: silver;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section><div class=narrow></div><div class=content></div></section>
```

Comment: I've been experimenting with this for years and I've come to the conclusion that it's impossible to show exactly 1px under all circumstances.

Comment: @JoshLee, I only need word wrap to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `webkit` it's possible with media queries:

```js
~function () {
  var s = "When silver div gets too wide it should jump down..."
  var i = s.length
  var div = document.querySelector(".content");

  setInterval(function () {
    div.textContent = s.slice(0, i = ++i % (s.length + 1))
  }, 100)
}()
```

```css
section {
  width: 15em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.narrow {
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .1 )   { .narrow { width: 10px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .25)   { .narrow { width:  4px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .3 )   { .narrow { width:  3px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: .5 )   { .narrow { width:  2px; } }
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1  )   { .narrow { width:  1px; } }

.content {
  background: silver;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section><div class=narrow></div><div class=content></div></section>
```